# PHP, CURL. What does curl_exec returns a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, api

I'm trying to set an API wit a CMS.  The api code works fine. When I use `var_dump` the data I get is given below. I just want to extract records from it.

```
string(9219) "{"Details":{"PageNo":1,"TotalRecords":21,"TotalPages":6,"MethodName":"GetEntity"},"Error":{"ErrorCode":"200","ErrorDescription":"Request Successfully Accommodated"},"Records":[{"RecordId":"79245","Deleted":"N","CancellationWithNoRefund":"N","ShowOnWeb":"Y","BookNowOverrideOnWeb":"","WaitingListByEventOrSession":"","Active":"Y","Archive":"","DinnerType":"","StandardDay":"","EvacuationAssistanceRequired":"","IncludesMeals":"","FieldTrip":"","CpdAssignedToDelegate":"","Master":"","EventMaster":"","EnableApologies":"","MemberOnly":"N","AllowTableBooking":"","ExamDate":"","ExpiryDate":"","ArrivalDate":"","DepartDate":"","CutOffDate":"2021-12-20 00:00:00.000","BookingDeadline":"","StartDate":"2021-12-21 00:00:00.000","EndDate":"2021-12-21 00:00:00.000","DateDeleted":"","DateModified":"20/07/2021 14:53:14","DateCreated":"20/07/2021 13:30:11","NoOfDays":"1","AccreditionPoints":"","TotalTba":"0","MaximumSeats":"64","MinimumSeats":"1","TotalBookings":"1","TotalCancellations":"0","TotalRemoved":"","SeatsAvailable":"63","TotalOnWaitingList":"0","WaitingLimitPercentage":"12.5","WaitingLimitNumber":"8","EventCpdHours":"","MaximumAdditionalDelegates":"4","CommitteeName":"","SpeakerTutorOrganisationName":"","EventCode":"","ExpiryDaysName":"","ResponsibilityName":"","JoiningInstructions":"Further instructions will be emailed out ","RegionName":"Southe","Location":"","PromotionalCodeName":"","EventUrl":"","CampaignAppealName":"","CostCentreName":"","InternalId":"","SpeakerTutorName":"","LedgerAccountName":"","MainContactName":"","VatRateName":"Standard 20%","EventTypeName":"Golf Day","EventStatusName":"Open","VenueName":"Foxhills Golf Club & Resort","RegistrationTime":"","DeletedBy":"","EventName":"Golf Day 2021 SL","FomalTitle":"Golf Day 2021 SL","SourceFile":"","EventId":"Golf Day SL ","CreatedBy":"Sarah Lepak","ModifiedBy":"Sarah Lepak","LongDescription":"","Remarks":"","BookNowOverrideMessage":"","AccommodationNotes":"","NotesForWeb":"SL test golf day 2021","TCForWeb":"T's & C's here","ShortNotesForWeb":"","Committee":"","Responsibility":"","PromotionalCode":"","Region":"19053","SpeakerTutorOrganisation":"","ExpiryDays":"","CampaignAppeal":"","CostCentre":"","MainContact":"","Venue":"79240","EventStatus":"241","EventType":"227","LedgerAccount":"","VatRate":"19112","SpeakerTutor":"","StartTime":"10:30","EndTime":"16:00","WaitingListBy":"Event","CpdBy":"","SiteLayout":""},{"RecordId":"79244","Deleted":"N","CancellationWithNoRefund":"N","ShowOnWeb":"Y","BookNowOverrideOnWeb":"","WaitingListByEventOrSession":"","Active":"Y","Archive":"","DinnerType":"","StandardDay":"","EvacuationAssistanceRequired":"","IncludesMeals":"","FieldTrip":"","CpdAssignedToDelegate":"","Master":"","EventMaster":"","EnableApologies":"","MemberOnly":"N","AllowTableBooking":"","ExamDate":"","ExpiryDate":"","ArrivalDate":"","DepartDate":"","CutOffDate":"2021-09-20 00:00:00.000","BookingDeadline":"","StartDate":"2021-09-21 00:00:00.000","EndDate":"2021-09-21 00:00:00.000","DateDeleted":"","DateModified":"20/07/2021 13:30:03","DateCreated":"20/07/2021 13:30:01","NoOfDays":"1","AccreditionPoints":"","TotalTba":"0","MaximumSeats":"64","MinimumSeats":"1","TotalBookings":"0","TotalCancellations":"0","TotalRemoved":"","SeatsAvailable":"64","TotalOnWaitingList":"0","WaitingLimitPercentage":"78.13","WaitingLimitNumber":"50","EventCpdHours":"","MaximumAdditionalDelegates":"4","CommitteeName":"","SpeakerTutorOrganisationName":"","EventCode":"","ExpiryDaysName":"","ResponsibilityName":"","JoiningInstructions":"","RegionName":"Southe","Location":"","PromotionalCodeName":"","EventUrl":"","CampaignAppealName":"","CostCentreName":"","InternalId":"","SpeakerTutorName":"","LedgerAccountName":"","MainContactName":"","VatRateName":"Standard 20%","EventTypeName":"Golf Day","EventStatusName":"Open","VenueName":"Foxhills Golf Club & Resort","RegistrationTime":"","DeletedBy":"","EventName":"CB Golf Experience 2021","FomalTitle":"CB Golf Experience 2021","SourceFile":"","EventId":"CBGE21","CreatedBy":"Calvin Barnett","ModifiedBy":"Calvin Barnett","LongDescription":"","Remarks":"","BookNowOverrideMessage":"","AccommodationNotes":"","NotesForWeb":"Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum","TCForWeb":"Cancellations more than 14 days ahead of the event will incur an administration fee of 10% per person deducted from their refund\r\n28 days ahead or less - a 50% refund will be given\r\n14 days ahead or less – no refunds will be given","ShortNotesForWeb":"","Committee":"","Responsibility":"","PromotionalCode":"","Region":"19053","SpeakerTutorOrganisation":"","ExpiryDays":"","CampaignAppeal":"","CostCentre":"","MainContact":"","Venue":"79240","EventStatus":"241","EventType":"227","LedgerAccount":"","VatRate":"19112","SpeakerTutor":"","StartTime":"14:00","EndTime":"17:00","WaitingListBy":"Event","CpdBy":"","SiteLayout":""},{"RecordId":"79243","Deleted":"N","CancellationWithNoRefund":"N","ShowOnWeb":"N","BookNowOverrideOnWeb":"","WaitingListByEventOrSession":"","Active":"Y","Archive":"","DinnerType":"","StandardDay":"","EvacuationAssistanceRequired":"","IncludesMeals":"","FieldTrip":"","CpdAssignedToDelegate":"","Master":"","EventMaster":"","EnableApologies":"","MemberOnly":"N","AllowTableBooking":"","ExamDate":"","ExpiryDate":"","ArrivalDate":"","DepartDate":"","CutOffDate":"","BookingDeadline":"","StartDate":"2022-08-30 00:00:00.000","EndDate":"2022-08-30 00:00:00.000","DateDeleted":"","DateModified":"20/07/2021 14:48:13","DateCreated":"20/07/2021 13:29:59","NoOfDays":"1","AccreditionPoints":"","TotalTba":"0","MaximumSeats":"65","MinimumSeats":"1","TotalBookings":"1","TotalCancellations":"0","TotalRemoved":"","SeatsAvailable":"64","TotalOnWaitingList":"0","WaitingLimitPercentage":"","WaitingLimitNumber":"","EventCpdHours":"","MaximumAdditionalDelegates":"4","CommitteeName":"","SpeakerTutorOrganisationName":"","EventCode":"","ExpiryDaysName":"","ResponsibilityName":"","JoiningInstructions":"","RegionName":"Eastmids","Location":"West lobby","PromotionalCodeName":"","EventUrl":"","CampaignAppealName":"","CostCentreName":"","InternalId":"","SpeakerTutorName":"","LedgerAccountName":"","MainContactName":"","VatRateName":"Standard 20%","EventTypeName":"Golf Day","EventStatusName":"Open","VenueName":"MilYork Test Venue","RegistrationTime":"","DeletedBy":"","EventName":"MY Golf Day 2022","FomalTitle":"MY Golf Day 2022","SourceFile":"","EventId":"MYGD22","CreatedBy":"Dawn Hall","ModifiedBy":"Dawn Hall","LongDescription":"","Remarks":"","BookNowOverrideMessage":"","AccommodationNotes":"","NotesForWeb":"Park in West wing carpark","TCForWeb":"This is a CRM test.","ShortNotesForWeb":"","Committee":"","Responsibility":"","PromotionalCode":"","Region":"19046","SpeakerTutorOrganisation":"","ExpiryDays":"","CampaignAppeal":"","CostCentre":"","MainContact":"","Venue":"77113","EventStatus":"241","EventType":"227","LedgerAccount":"","VatRate":"19112","SpeakerTutor":"","StartTime":"08:00","EndTime":"19:00","WaitingListBy":"Session","CpdBy":"","SiteLayout":""},{"RecordId":"79242","Deleted":"N","CancellationWithNoRefund":"N","ShowOnWeb":"Y","BookNowOverrideOnWeb":"","WaitingListByEventOrSession":"","Active":"Y","Archive":"","DinnerType":"","StandardDay":"","EvacuationAssistanceRequired":"","IncludesMeals":"","FieldTrip":"","CpdAssignedToDelegate":"","Master":"","EventMaster":"","EnableApologies":"","MemberOnly":"N","AllowTableBooking":"","ExamDate":"","ExpiryDate":"","ArrivalDate":"","DepartDate":"","CutOffDate":"2021-09-08 00:00:00.000","BookingDeadline":"","StartDate":"2021-09-08 00:00:00.000","EndDate":"2021-09-08 00:00:00.000","DateDeleted":"","DateModified":"20/07/2021 13:29:29","DateCreated":"20/07/2021 13:29:28","NoOfDays":"1","AccreditionPoints":"","TotalTba":"0","MaximumSeats":"64","MinimumSeats":"1","TotalBookings":"0","TotalCancellations":"0","TotalRemoved":"","SeatsAvailable":"64","TotalOnWaitingList":"0","WaitingLimitPercentage":"18.75","WaitingLimitNumber":"12","EventCpdHours":"","MaximumAdditionalDelegates":"4","CommitteeName":"","SpeakerTutorOrganisationName":"","EventCode":"","ExpiryDaysName":"","ResponsibilityName":"","JoiningInstructions":"First come first serve basis","RegionName":"Southe","Location":"","PromotionalCodeName":"","EventUrl":"","CampaignAppealName":"","CostCentreName":"","InternalId":"","SpeakerTutorName":"","LedgerAccountName":"","MainContactName":"","VatRateName":"Standard 20%","EventTypeName":"Golf Day","EventStatusName":"Open","VenueName":"Foxhills Golf Club & Resort","RegistrationTime":"","DeletedBy":"","EventName":"Annual Golf Day 2021 - CL Version","FomalTitle":"Annual Golf Day 2021 - CL Version","SourceFile":"","EventId":"CL- GD21","CreatedBy":"Charlie Lawrence","ModifiedBy":"Charlie Lawrence","LongDescription":"","Remarks":"","BookNowOverrideMessage":"","AccommodationNotes":"","NotesForWeb":"Annual Golf Day 2021","TCForWeb":"","ShortNotesForWeb":"","Committee":"","Responsibility":"","PromotionalCode":"","Region":"19053","SpeakerTutorOrganisation":"","ExpiryDays":"","CampaignAppeal":"","CostCentre":"","MainContact":"","Venue":"79240","EventStatus":"241","EventType":"227","LedgerAccount":"","VatRate":"19112","SpeakerTutor":"","StartTime":"08:00","EndTime":"16:00","WaitingListBy":"Session","CpdBy":"","SiteLayout":""}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The API is returning a JSON string. Please try

`$result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));`

$result is a php array.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now getting this .

Answer (score 0):

Getting this reposes from the answer you provided.
How can I get the records only.

stdClass Object ( [Details] => stdClass Object ( [PageNo] => 1 [TotalRecords] => 21 [TotalPages] => 6 [MethodName] => GetEntity ) [Error] => stdClass Object ( [ErrorCode] => 200 [ErrorDescription] => Request Successfully Accommodated ) [Records] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [RecordId] => 79245 [Deleted] => N [CancellationWithNoRefund] => N [ShowOnWeb] => Y [BookNowOverrideOnWeb] => [WaitingListByEventOrSession] => [Active] => Y [Archive] => [DinnerType] => [StandardDay] => [EvacuationAssistanceRequired] => [IncludesMeals] => [FieldTrip] => [CpdAssignedToDelegate] => [Master] => [EventMaster] => [EnableApologies] => [MemberOnly] => N [AllowTableBooking] => [ExamDate] => [ExpiryDate] => [ArrivalDate] => [DepartDate] => [CutOffDate] => 2021-12-20 00:00:00.000 [BookingDeadline] => [StartDate] => 2021-12-21 00:00:00.000 [EndDate] => 2021-12-21 00:00:00.000 [DateDeleted] => [DateModified] => 20/07/2021 14:53:14 [DateCreated] => 20/07/2021 13:30:11 [NoOfDays] => 1 [AccreditionPoints] => [TotalTba] => 0 [MaximumSeats] => 64 [MinimumSeats] => 1 [TotalBookings] => 1 [TotalCancellations] => 0 [TotalRemoved] => [SeatsAvailable] => 63 [TotalOnWaitingList] => 0 [WaitingLimitPercentage] => 12.5 [WaitingLimitNumber] => 8 [EventCpdHours] => [MaximumAdditionalDelegates] => 4 [CommitteeName] => [SpeakerTutorOrganisationName] => [EventCode] => [ExpiryDaysName] => [ResponsibilityName] => [JoiningInstructions] => Further instructions will be emailed out [RegionName] => Southe [Location] => [PromotionalCodeName] => [EventUrl] => [CampaignAppealName] => [CostCentreName] => [InternalId] => [SpeakerTutorName] => [LedgerAccountName] => [MainContactName] => [VatRateName] => Standard 20% [EventTypeName] => Golf Day [EventStatusName] => Open [VenueName] => Foxhills Golf Club & Resort [RegistrationTime] => [DeletedBy] => [EventName] => Golf Day 2021 SL [FomalTitle] => Golf Day 2021 SL [SourceFile] => [EventId] => Golf Day SL [CreatedBy] => Sarah Lepak [ModifiedBy] => Sarah Lepak [LongDescription] => [Remarks] => [BookNowOverrideMessage] => [AccommodationNotes] => [NotesForWeb] => SL test golf day 2021 [TCForWeb] => T's & C's here [ShortNotesForWeb] => [Committee] => [Responsibility] => [PromotionalCode] => [Region] => 19053 [SpeakerTutorOrganisation] => [ExpiryDays] => [CampaignAppeal] => [CostCentre] => [MainContact] => [Venue] => 79240 [EventStatus] => 241 [EventType] => 227 [LedgerAccount] => [VatRate] => 19112 [SpeakerTutor] => [StartTime] => 10:30 [EndTime] => 16:00 [WaitingListBy] => Event [CpdBy] => [SiteLayout] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [RecordId] => 79244 [Deleted] => N [CancellationWithNoRefund] => N [ShowOnWeb] => Y [BookNowOverrideOnWeb] => [WaitingListByEventOrSession] => [Active] => Y [Archive] => [DinnerType] => [StandardDay] => [EvacuationAssistanceRequired] => [IncludesMeals] => [FieldTrip] => [CpdAssignedToDelegate] => [Master] => [EventMaster] => [EnableApologies] => [MemberOnly] => N [AllowTableBooking] => [ExamDate] => [ExpiryDate] => [ArrivalDate] => [DepartDate] => [CutOffDate] => 2021-09-20 00:00:00.000 [BookingDeadline] => [StartDate] => 2021-09-21 00:00:00.000 [EndDate] => 2021-09-21 00:00:00.000 [DateDeleted] => [DateModified] => 20/07/2021 13:30:03 [DateCreated] => 20/07/2021 13:30:01 [NoOfDays] => 1 [AccreditionPoints] => [TotalTba] => 0 [MaximumSeats] => 64 [MinimumSeats] => 1 [TotalBookings] => 0 [TotalCancellations] => 0 [TotalRemoved] => [SeatsAvailable] => 64 [TotalOnWaitingList] => 0 [WaitingLimitPercentage] => 78.13 [WaitingLimitNumber] => 50 [EventCpdHours] => [MaximumAdditionalDelegates] => 4 [CommitteeName] => [SpeakerTutorOrganisationName] => [EventCode] => [ExpiryDaysName] => [ResponsibilityName] => [JoiningInstructions] => [RegionName] => Southe [Location] => [PromotionalCodeName] => [EventUrl] => [CampaignAppealName] => [CostCentreName] => [InternalId] => [SpeakerTutorName] => [LedgerAccountName] => [MainContactName] => [VatRateName] => Standard 20% [EventTypeName] => Golf Day [EventStatusName] => Open [VenueName] => Foxhills Golf Club & Resort [RegistrationTime] => [DeletedBy] => [EventName] => CB Golf Experience 2021 [FomalTitle] => CB Golf Experience 2021 [SourceFile] => [EventId] => CBGE21 [CreatedBy] => Calvin Barnett [ModifiedBy] => Calvin Barnett [LongDescription] => [Remarks] => [BookNowOverrideMessage] => [AccommodationNotes] => [NotesForWeb] => Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum [TCForWeb] => Cancellations more than 14 days ahead of the event will incur an administration fee of 10% per person deducted from their refund 28 days ahead or less - a 50% refund will be given 14 days ahead or less – no refunds will be given [ShortNotesForWeb] => [Committee] => [Responsibility] => [PromotionalCode] => [Region] => 19053 [SpeakerTutorOrganisation] => [ExpiryDays] => [CampaignAppeal] => [CostCentre] => [MainContact] => [Venue] => 79240 [EventStatus] => 241 [EventType] => 227 [LedgerAccount] => [VatRate] => 19112 [SpeakerTutor] => [StartTime] => 14:00 [EndTime] => 17:00 [WaitingListBy] => Event [CpdBy] => [SiteLayout] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [RecordId] => 79243 [Deleted] => N [CancellationWithNoRefund] => N [ShowOnWeb] => N [BookNowOverrideOnWeb] => [WaitingListByEventOrSession] => [Active] => Y [Archive] => [DinnerType] => [StandardDay] => [EvacuationAssistanceRequired] => [IncludesMeals] => [FieldTrip] => [CpdAssignedToDelegate] => [Master] => [EventMaster] => [EnableApologies] => [MemberOnly] => N [AllowTableBooking] => [ExamDate] => [ExpiryDate] => [ArrivalDate] => [DepartDate] => [CutOffDate] => [BookingDeadline] => [StartDate] => 2022-08-30 00:00:00.000 [EndDate] => 2022-08-30 00:00:00.000 [DateDeleted] => [DateModified] => 20/07/2021 14:48:13 [DateCreated] => 20/07/2021 13:29:59 [NoOfDays] => 1 [AccreditionPoints] => [TotalTba] => 0 [MaximumSeats] => 65 [MinimumSeats] => 1 [TotalBookings] => 1 [TotalCancellations] => 0 [TotalRemoved] => [SeatsAvailable] => 64 [TotalOnWaitingList] => 0 [WaitingLimitPercentage] => [WaitingLimitNumber] => [EventCpdHours] => [MaximumAdditionalDelegates] => 4 [CommitteeName] => [SpeakerTutorOrganisationName] => [EventCode] => [ExpiryDaysName] => [ResponsibilityName] => [JoiningInstructions] => [RegionName] => Eastmids [Location] => West lobby [PromotionalCodeName] => [EventUrl] => [CampaignAppealName] => [CostCentreName] => [InternalId] => [SpeakerTutorName] => [LedgerAccountName] => [MainContactName] => [VatRateName] => Standard 20% [EventTypeName] => Golf Day [EventStatusName] => Open [VenueName] => MilYork Test Venue [RegistrationTime] => [DeletedBy] => [EventName] => MY Golf Day 2022 [FomalTitle] => MY Golf Day 2022 [SourceFile] => [EventId] => MYGD22 [CreatedBy] => Dawn Hall [ModifiedBy] => Dawn Hall [LongDescription] => [Remarks] => [BookNowOverrideMessage] => [AccommodationNotes] => [NotesForWeb] => Park in West wing carpark [TCForWeb] => This is a CRM test. [ShortNotesForWeb] => [Committee] => [Responsibility] => [PromotionalCode] => [Region] => 19046 [SpeakerTutorOrganisation] => [ExpiryDays] => [CampaignAppeal] => [CostCentre] => [MainContact] => [Venue] => 77113 [EventStatus] => 241 [EventType] => 227 [LedgerAccount] => [VatRate] => 19112 [SpeakerTutor] => [StartTime] => 08:00 [EndTime] => 19:00 [WaitingListBy] => Session [CpdBy] => [SiteLayout] => ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [RecordId] => 79242 [Deleted] => N [CancellationWithNoRefund] => N [ShowOnWeb] => Y [BookNowOverrideOnWeb] => [WaitingListByEventOrSession] => [Active] => Y [Archive] => [DinnerType] => [StandardDay] => [EvacuationAssistanceRequired] => [IncludesMeals] => [FieldTrip] => [CpdAssignedToDelegate] => [Master] => [EventMaster] => [EnableApologies] => [MemberOnly] => N [AllowTableBooking] => [ExamDate] => [ExpiryDate] => [ArrivalDate] => [DepartDate] => [CutOffDate] => 2021-09-08 00:00:00.000 [BookingDeadline] => [StartDate] => 2021-09-08 00:00:00.000 [EndDate] => 2021-09-08 00:00:00.000 [DateDeleted] => [DateModified] => 20/07/2021 13:29:29 [DateCreated] => 20/07/2021 13:29:28 [NoOfDays] => 1 [AccreditionPoints] => [TotalTba] => 0 [MaximumSeats] => 64 [MinimumSeats] => 1 [TotalBookings] => 0 [TotalCancellations] => 0 [TotalRemoved] => [SeatsAvailable] => 64 [TotalOnWaitingList] => 0 [WaitingLimitPercentage] => 18.75 [WaitingLimitNumber] => 12 [EventCpdHours] => [MaximumAdditionalDelegates] => 4 [CommitteeName] => [SpeakerTutorOrganisationName] => [EventCode] => [ExpiryDaysName] => [ResponsibilityName] => [JoiningInstructions] => First come first serve basis [RegionName] => Southe [Location] => [PromotionalCodeName] => [EventUrl] => [CampaignAppealName] => [CostCentreName] => [InternalId] => [SpeakerTutorName] => [LedgerAccountName] => [MainContactName] => [VatRateName] => Standard 20% [EventTypeName] => Golf Day [EventStatusName] => Open [VenueName] => Foxhills Golf Club & Resort [RegistrationTime] => [DeletedBy] => [EventName] => Annual Golf Day 2021 - CL Version [FomalTitle] => Annual Golf Day 2021 - CL Version [SourceFile] => [EventId] => CL- GD21 [CreatedBy] => Charlie Lawrence [ModifiedBy] => Charlie Lawrence [LongDescription] => [Remarks] => [BookNowOverrideMessage] => [AccommodationNotes] => [NotesForWeb] => Annual Golf Day 2021 [TCForWeb] => [ShortNotesForWeb] => [Committee] => [Responsibility] => [PromotionalCode] => [Region] => 19053 [SpeakerTutorOrganisation] => [ExpiryDays] => [CampaignAppeal] => [CostCentre] => [MainContact] => [Venue] => 79240 [EventStatus] => 241 [EventType] => 227 [LedgerAccount] => [VatRate] => 19112 [SpeakerTutor] => [StartTime] => 08:00 [EndTime] => 16:00 [WaitingListBy] => Session [CpdBy] => [SiteLayout] => ) ) )